# Universal Image Loader reuse images in android

Tags: android

Using Universal Image Loader, is it possible to directly save images to disk and reuse those images between different runs of the application?
I know `imageLoader.displayImage(imageURI, itemHolder.image, options);` gets images from the cache the second time, but if you exit the app the cache is removed.
I want the display image method to save the image to a permanent location and use that location every time the app calls that method.
Is this possible using Universal Image Loader or do I need to find another way?

Comment: LazyList does it....have you tried it??it's also very simple to implement

Answer (score 0):

you need to download images to certain folder at first start up and after that you can load images using same method and you need to pass file location instead of url like:

imageLoader.displayImage("file:///sdcard/test.png", itemHolder.image, options);

Hope this will help you